# Adding custom JS to existing module causing errors

Tags: magento2, module, javascript, requirejs-config.js

So I've been trying to add some custom javascript to a module, however when the JS has added it works fine in itself, but it causes a lot of errors for a lot of different scripts, and I can't figure out how to stop it from causing that.

What I have done now is load the custom JS using the **`require-config.js`** in **`Module/Namespace/view/frontend`**, using the following code:

```
var config = {
map: {
    '*': {
        module: "Module_Namespace/js/view/customFolder/customScript",
    }
},

shim: {
    'module': {
        deps: ['jquery']
    }
},

deps: [
    "js/view/customFolder/customScript"
]
};
```

My custom script is located in **`Module/Namespace/view/frontend/web/js/view/customFolder/customScript.js`**.

If I use the regular js templates that Magento use the entire scripts won't work however:

```
define([
'jquery',
'jquery/ui'
], function ($) {
"use strict";

$.widget('namespace.customScript', {
    __create: function() {
        this.testAlert();
    },

    testAlert: function() {
        alert('testAlert');
    }
});

return $.namespace.customScript;
});
```

This will give the following error:

> Uncaught Error: Script error for: js/view/customFolder/customScript
>   http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror at makeError
>   (require.js:166) at HTMLScriptElement.onScriptError (require.js:1681)

Followed by alot of the following error:

> mixins.js:117 Uncaught TypeError: module.config is not a function at
>   Object.getMixins (mixins.js:117) at Object.hasMixins (mixins.js:138)
>   at processName (mixins.js:161) at Array.map () at
>   Object.processNames (mixins.js:169) at window.define (mixins.js:258)
>   at scripts.js:6

However, if I put an alert at the very top of the custom JS (above the define) it will replace all of the module.config errors with these:

> Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'config' of undefined
>        at Object.getMixins (mixins.js:117)
>        at Object.hasMixins (mixins.js:138)
>        at processName (mixins.js:161)
>        at Array.map ()
>        at Object.processNames (mixins.js:169)
>        at window.define (mixins.js:258)
>        at translate.js:9
>        at translate.js:16

I have no clue how to solve these errors, but I just need to load a simple javascript into an existing module. Is there a better way to do it than this, or can I try anything to debug/fix these errors?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: why do you need the "shim"? and why have you added "deps"? Seems unessecary to me

Comment: The tutorial I followed had those too, normally I just use the map part. I've tried it with and without the shim and deps, but it didn't really make a difference, so I'm honestly not sure why they should or shouldn't be there, but I just left them in in case.